# actionscript library for interactive path drawing (or any other library for the equations

Tags: actionscript-3, bezier

I am making a flash app where I want to have a user defined viewport like the stage in the flash IDE which the user can use to define objects that have a starting postition somerwhere off or on the stage and an ending position either or on or off the stage with the object then tweening between the two points.
My question is this:  I want the user to be able to define a curved path for the object to tween along.  Is there a library of code that I can use to define curved paths for the app?

Ideally I would like something similar to the functionality available in Flash, so a bezier curve sort of path that is subdivided into handles that can be dragged to define the path of the tween.

If there isn't an existing library, then do you know of the functions that I would need to define (mathematical equations related to drawing curves etc)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) with the [BezierPlugin](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.html)

Or define the path elsewhere and use [LinePath2D](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/motionPaths/LinePath2D.html)